# Load LLDB commands into XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

Has anyone loaded commands into LLDB for a debugging session of an XCode app.
I'm in XCode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.x

I don't know any Python, so id highly prefer avoiding having to involve Python.
I would like to load this stuff I type by hand from a file, so I don't have to keep typing it over and over each time I re-run the debug session...

```
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "SomeClass"
Breakpoint 10: 48 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "AnotherClass"
Breakpoint 11: 15 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "ThisClass"
Breakpoint 12: 15 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "ThatClass"
Breakpoint 13: 57 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "OurClass"
Breakpoint 14: 98 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "YourClass"
Breakpoint 15: 22 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "HerClass"
Breakpoint 16: 17 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "HisClass"
Breakpoint 17: 46 locations.
(lldb) breakpoint set --func-regex "TheyreClass"
Breakpoint 18: 63 locations.

(lldb) breakpoint command add 10
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command add 11
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info; continue; DONE
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command delete 11
(lldb) breakpoint command add 11
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command add 12
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command add 13
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command add 14
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command add 15
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command add 16
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command add 17
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
(lldb) breakpoint command add 18
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to set a breakpoint on the main() function of your app, and via the Xcode UI bind it to execute a debugger command of the form

```
command source <myMagicFile>
```

and then auto continue

The file would then contain the commands you want executed, and since the breakpoint is on main(), your file would get loaded and the commands executed each time you start debugging your app

As a hint, it is probably safer to add each breakpoint and then do breakpoint command add directly after. Breakpoint command add will then automatically refer to the last breakpoint you created, so you don't have to rely on breakpoint IDs

For instance:

```
breakpoint set --func-regex "SomeClass"
breakpoint command add
Enter your debugger command(s).  Type 'DONE' to end.
> frame info
> continue
> DONE
breakpoint set --func-regex "AnotherClass"
```

[...]